# an enter key are handled twice in WPF/Winform mixed project

Tags: wpf, winforms

I have a winform dashboard which hosts some WPF dialogs. When I select a row in the winform ListView and hit Enter key, OnItemActivate is called which launches a WPF dialog. However, the WPF dialog appears and then disappears immediately because the default button “cancel” is hit.  It seems that the Enter key is triggered twice, one for launching the WPF dialog, the other for hitting cancel button. We don’t want the WPF dialog to be canceled by the Enter key hitting.

According to the stack trace, it looks like that WPF and Winform handle the enter key separately. The WPF does not know that the enter key has been handled by the Winform ListView. Is this by design in Winform and WPF interop?

To make the enter key not close the WPF dialog, we have to change the focus from the cancel button to another control (e.g. a textblock). Is there a better way to fix/around this issue?

Comment: You might try WinForms `Application.DoEvents()` before showing the WPF dialog?  It might drain the message queue.  Also try `Thread.Sleep(10)` or handle the key up event instead of key down.

Comment: Interesting soutions! Could you give some sample code about "handle the key up event instead of key down"? In my current code, I handle ItemActivate event using _listView_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e). But I don't know how to get the key code from e. Do you know? Appreciate your help!

Comment: BTW, DoEvents() works and Thread.Sleep does not work. Thanks.

Comment: pls show ur code

Answer (score 0):

As Rick suggested in the comments, try calling Application.DoEvents() before opening the WPF dialog.